# Excel_VBA-IF condition = 1 , GO LOOP

Tags: excel, vba

i need help with VBA code.

My question is best seen.

[image]

In short:
Check condition, IF condition = TRUE
Go loop x times repeatedly , and after loop go check condition again.

Thank you very much for help! :)

Comment: You need to include code in your question. Pictures are not helpful.

Comment: this looks like homework.

Answer (score 0):

You will end up with a loop within a loop. The outer loop can be a `Do Until...` loop and the inner is probably best to implement using a `For` loop.

```
Sub test()
     Do Until Range("B10").Value <> "True" Then
         For i = 1 to 100
             'do whatever you are doing 100 times
         Next i
     Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## Don't run this.

```
'ON WORKSHEET
Sub Example()
    Dim i As Integer
    Do
        If Range("B10").Value Then
            For i = 1 To 100
                SomeFunction
            Next
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

<sup>Like your diagram, it will never exit.</sup>

Comment: Well.. it might exit if `SomeFunction` changes `Range("B10").value` at some point.

Comment: @JNevill The diagram or my code?  ;-)  I didn't see the diagram branching.

Comment: Both. If `somefunction` is `If now() mod 2 = 0 Then Range("B10").value = "False"` or something...

Comment: @JNevill - Huh? Like I said, I interpreted the diagram as not branching.  The only way the above code exits is if `Range("B10").Value` is true ***and*** `SomeFunction` contains the line: `End`

Comment: The diagram says `If Range("B10").Value = TRUE GO LOOP`.  That is implicitly stating that "GO LOOP" should not occur if Range("B10").Value = False, and thus the diagram has an implicit exit.

Comment: @YowE3K - I was reading as a flow diagram.  There is only one arrow coming out of that area of the diagram.  I'd say that only the OP *really* knows what is meant (which is why I also voted to close).

Comment: I think the point is that we don't know what `somefunction` is doing. It can change the value of `Range("B10")` based on some condition that may occur within the loop of 100 which may cause an exit on the next iteration.

Comment: @JNevill - Seriously? We're still talking about this? If you think my interpretation of the OP's drawing is wrong, just down-vote the answer.